# How does fwupd update the FMP UEFI capsule file ( cab file) generated from edk2?

Tags: linux

I used the example of edk2 platform to generate Red.16.cap and Red.16.cab, the source code is as follows:

```
https://github.com/tianocore/edk2-platforms/tree/master/Platform/Intel/Vlv2TbltDevicePkg
```

Where Red.16.cap is a dummy test example and does not actually update the firmware.
I execute the following command in UEFI shell to update fmp UEFI capsule successfully:
capsuleapp Red.16.cap
My system is as follows:

```
Minnowboard Max
UEFI x64
Linux fedora 6.0.5-200.fc36.x86_64
```

I execute following command n fedora,

```
sudo fwupdmgr install Red.16.cab
```

After the end, it shows the following messages:
Successfully installed firmware.Restart Now?[y|N]
After choosing to restart, I see the following error message under UEFI:

```
Unknown Capsule Guid - 72E2945A-00DA-448E-9AA7-075AD840F9D4
WARNING: QueryCapsuleCapabilities failed, assuming EfiResetWarm: Unsupported
Unknown Capsule Guid - 72E2945A-00DA-448E-9AA7-075AD840F9D4
WARNING: Could not apply capsule update: Unsupported
WARNING: Could not apply capsules: Unsupported
```

It can be seen that the fwupd update fw did not succeed。

I execute `‘sudo fwupdmgr get-devices’` on fedora and got the following messages:

```
─UEFI Device Firmware:
│ │ Device ID: f95c9218acd12697af946874bfe4239587209232
│ │ Previous version: 1
│ │ Update State: Needs reboot
│ │ Last modified: 2022-07-14 00:19
│ │ GUID: 72e2945a-00da-448e-9aa7-075ad840f9d4
│ │ Device Flags: • Internal device
│ │ • Updatable
│ │ • System requires external power source
│ │ • Needs a reboot after installation
│ │ • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│ │
│ └─ New version: 16
│ License: Unknown
│ Description:
│ The vendor did not supply any release notes.
```

As can be seen from GenCapsuleAll.py of edk2:

```
GenCapsuleSampleDevice('Red','72e2945a-00da-448e-9aa7-075ad840f9d4',0x00000010,0x00000000, CapsulesPath, CapsulesSubDir)
```

The Capsule Guid can be found by fwupd, but the system reboot shows Unknown Capsule Guid’.

By the way, after updating Red.16.cab, I have successfully restarted Linux, but after restarting, it shows that it needs to be restarted.
My questions are as follows:

1.Update Red.16.cap in UEFI shell, restarts system and it got the following messages

```
Setting BootMode to BOOT_ON_S3_RESUME
```

And restart after fwupd update Red.16.cab, see the following UEFI message:

```
Setting BootMode to BOOT_WITH_FULL_CONFIGURATION
```

It can be seen that the mode of the two is different after UEFI restarts. Is it correct that fwupd does not enter S3_RESUME mode after restarting?

2.Can the cab file generated in edk2 be updated directly in fwupd? Or what to modify before executing fwupd?

3.Does fwupd have other samples to test UEFI capsule(cab) update? Are there detailed operating procedures?

Any suggestion is highly appreciated!

Thanks!